# Bitwise operations in Bash

Tags: bash, bit-manipulation

How do I do a bit-wise AND operation on a Bash variable? I want to test individual bits in a program's exit code. Something like:

```
myprog
BITS=$?
if [ $BITS & 4 ]; then
  echo "Bit 2 set"
fi
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use bash arithmetic expansion:

```
if (( BITS & 4 )); then
```

Comment: You can even specify that magic number `4` in base 2 to make your intend more clear: `(( BITS & 2#100 ))`.

Comment: It took me a while to find this answer; I had a full question typed before SO deigned to show this to me.
I wound up doing a line like `(( BITS & 8 )) && echo "stuff here"` for each bit, which was super useful in my situation.  Elegant bitwise parsing FTW!